# БЕСПРЕДЕЛ Your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 416 days

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, чат, блокировка

**Я хотел бы знать причину почему меня заблокировали на 416 дней в чате**

Раз уж вы такой важный моедартор и "справедливый" модератор **@Nicolas Chabanovsky** то хочу вам напомнить о том что вы таким далеко не являетесь, так как за вами было замеченно то что вы закрывали глаза на участников которые общались в дискусии которая не относилась теме этого сайта, причем неоднократно, но никаких действий в их сторону выполненно небыло. А в мою были, и не однократно.

Comment: Даже если несправедливо и обидно: для обсуждения таких вопросов - Мета. Обратил внимание: ник автора вопроса - практически дубль названия ресурса. Это как китайская подделка? :)

Comment: `вдруг меня наградят медалью спамера, и удалят/заблокируют мой аккаунт за распространение дубликатов постов.` если вы будете оффтопить на основном сайте такими постами, то тогда вас точно заанят. инфа 100%

Comment: 416 — это как-то много. Мои соболезнования.

Comment: Теперь чат переехал в комментарии к этому вопросу :)

Comment: @VladD на месяц его уже банили, как я понимаю, это следующий по порядку срок.

Comment: @VladD действительно, блокировки на 416 дней ещё не было. Не представляю, откуда именно такое число.

Comment: Спасибо тебе Vlad.

Comment: Ничего не имею против вас, тем не менее добавил вас в игнор в чате, думаю, вы согласны, что это личное дело каждого, выбирать, чьи сообщения видеть. Но бан на полтора года за флуд во флуд-чате, мне видится слишком большим.

Comment: Я согласен что 416 дней это довольно много, но потеря весьма незначительна. Also inb4 мульты, новые баны и новые посты на мету.

Comment: Вы сейчас расстроены, и только отягощаете ситуацию своими высказываниями. Подождите немного, и попробуйте ещё раз, без лишних оскорблений и эмоций предложить модераторам рассмотреть ваш случай.

Answer (score 12):

## Взгляд со стороны

1. Вы пишете очень много, часто неграмотно и довольно бессвязно, без какой-либо связи с контекстом. Вы пишете всем и отвечаете на множество сообщений, адресованных не вам. Ваших сообщений в чате просто очень много и они мешают другим участникам комфортно общаться. Например:

   > О ! А теперь расскажите мне, что должен знать человек что бы стать синьор девелоперов в PHP, можно через запятую, т.е по нарастающей, я тоже хочу изучить хорошо PHP но я как бы его знаю, но образно можно сказать, смотря какие задачи стоят, но мне бы хотелсь узнать что думаете вы по этому поводу
2. Вы не реагируете на конструктивную критику. Я [писал вам в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32379773#32379773), Nicolas писал личное сообщение. Моё сообщение в чате вы проигнорировали, от личного сообщения отшутились. Другие участники тоже пытались объяснить ([пример](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32391618#32391618)), в чём дело, практически безуспешно.

Можно сделать вывод, что обращаться к вам с конструктивными предложениями не имеет смысла. Какой способ остаётся? Заблокировать и подождать, пока вы самостоятельно прочитаете правила и/или начнёте вести себя более по-взрослому.

Задача модератора — поддержать порядок на сайте. Всегда, когда это возможно, мы стараемся объяснить человеку, в чём его действия не соответствуют правилам сайта или принятым нормам сообщества. Так же было и с вами, так что жалобы на беспредел неуместны. Вы старательно игнорировали призывы к порядку и получили то, к чему стремились.

> Я считаю. что вы прывашаете полномочия и рассматриваете кандидатуру на бан лично в своих целях !

Вы знаете, это уже немного похоже на эгоцентризм . У меня (и у других модераторов, насколько я знаю), нет каких-то личных отношений с вами, чтобы 
банить в личных целях.

> Жалобы уместны, так как никто кроме вас модераторов не жалуется.На мои сообщения.
>   вы решаете сами кому я мешаю а кому нет хоть таковых заявлений от моих сообщений небыло

12 звездочек на [моём сообщении в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32379773#32379773) намекают, что как минимум 12 участников чата согласны, что вы могли бы писать меньше, но качественнее.

> Если бы ранк у меня был по выше могу поспорить ничего подобного бы небыло

Отнюдь. В разное время были блокированы участники, имеющие до 30000 репутации. Чаще на основном сайте, чем в чате.

> Что если я такой какой есть

Этот аргумент не может оправдывать какое-либо поведение, потому что это вообще не аргумент, а банальщина. Мы все такие, какие есть. Но мы осознаём принятые в обществе правила и стараемся им соответствовать.

> Наоборот некоторые поддерживали мои беседы и отвечали на вопросы. Но они тут наврятли напишут, так как мнимое уважение и профессионализм не даст им опустится в мою поддержку.

Я [обратился](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32550489#32550489) к участникам чата с предложением выступить в вашу защиту, если им есть что сказать.

Comment: бан на год с гаком, имхо, многовато.  Но опять же, в случае разбана я бы на  месте пострадавшего @StackOverFollow принял меры к тому, чтобы  меньше флудить без запятых и обращать внимание на пожелания модераторов и советы участников.

Comment: Также была и другая ветка в чате, где говорилось не о запятых, а именно о том, что "слишком много в чате": http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32391618#32391618 - и там же чуть ниже фраза "Да, возможно вы правы на счет времени". Очень жаль, что дошло до вмешательств модератора, я вижу упущенные возможности самостоятельно скорректировать своё поведение с учётом мнения общественности.

Answer (score 12):

Модераторы молодцы. Всё правильно сделали. Не место на сайте людям, пишущим в чат такие сообщения:

1. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32288506#32288506
2. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32288611#32288611
3. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32288676#32288676

А с учётом того, что это седьмой бан и предупреждения были неоднократны и жалобы от участников были и вообще драма случилась, то, считаю, обсуждать тут нечего.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры, они хорошо показывают, что бан был полностью оправданным.

Comment: По ссылкам вполне безобидные сообщения.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну, в определённых кругах бывает и не такое считается нормой, но, кмк, у нас тут сложился более высокий уровень дискуссии и не хотелось бы его понижать.

Answer (score 11):

#### Сроки блокировки доступа к учётной записи

На сайте действует экспоненциальная система нарастания блокировки. Сроки блокировки:

- 7 дней, за первое серьезное нарушение.
- 30 дней, за втрое серьезное нарушение.
- 365 дней, за третье серьезное нарушение.
- Бесконечная блокировка доступа к учетной записи, за последующие серьезное нарушение правил сообщества.

#### Проблема шума

Stack Overflow – *профессиональное* сообщество разработчиков, инструмент, который мы, программисты, используем в повседневной деятельности. Чем меньше шума в сообществе, тем эффективнее наша работа. Первоочередная задача проектировщиков системы – оградить сообщество от вредоносного шума. Как результат, все, что не касается тематики сайта, было вынесено на Мету и в чаты. Это не означает, что Мета или чаты являются местом, где можно терроризировать сообщество. У каждого из этих инструментов есть свое назначение.

#### Конкретный случай

Как вы можете видеть из вашей учетной записи в чате, это *седьмая* по счету блокировка. К сожалению, это моя вина, так как, согласно правилам сообществ, уже за третье нарушение срок блокировки должен был быть длиной в год.

Во время последних блокировок с вами связывались и просили пересмотреть ваш стиль взаимодействия в сообществе. (Как минимум, вы могли вынести крайне развернутые диалоги совершенно не связанные с тематикой сайта из главного чата сообщества в отдельный чат с конкретным участником, либо группой участников.)

Каждый раз перед блокировкой, перечитывались большинство ваших сообщений, на основании которых был сделан вывод, что, в большинстве случаев, вы не ведете диалог с кем–либо, а просто пытаетесь создать вредоносный шум, отвлекающий других участников от их деятельности, пытаясь навязать ненужный им диалог. Это типичный пример деструктивных действий, о чем вам не раз писалось.

Comment: *местом, где можно терроризировать сообщество* -- воу-воу-воу, это общая фраза, или здесь что-то такое имело место? Я просто не помню ничего такого, но я допускаю, что мог это пропустить. Возможно, для большей убедительности стоит снабдить ключевые места ссылками на конкретные сообщения в чате.

Comment: @D-side В моем понимании, к «терроризированию» сообщества можно отнести те случае, когда участник без каких–либо предпосылок начинает диалог с другим человеком и, что главное, продолжает его, хотя «собеседник» не ответил ни на одну из многих предыдущих фраз. Представьте, что на работе, когда вы заняты непосредственно работой, к вам подходит незнакомый инженер из соседнего отдела, бесцеремонно садится на стол, заслоняя монитор и начинает рассказывать про свою дачу. Ничего плохого, просто саженцы, урожай, строительство.

Comment: Неприятно, конечно. Добавите примеры?

Comment: @D-side Какой из? В логах чата уйма [примеров](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32288265#32288265), когда данный участник откровенно пристает. Вы можете самостоятельно прочитать транскрипт чата (как минимум с пару десятков сообщений от ссылки, что я указал).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky манеру общения очень точно описали.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на мой взгляд, это стоит добавить в ответ. Их уйма, легко найти, но лицу со стороны **надо искать**, чтобы понять о чём речь.

Comment: Я в предыдущем ответе приводил ссылку, там не один конкретный пример, там уже "сводка": http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32391618#32391618

Comment: Фига се я пропустил драму) По приведённой ссылке вообще лютый адЪ. Бан заслуженный, спасибо @NicolasChabanovsky.

Comment: Для будущих читателей. `Чем меньше шума в сообществе, тем эффективнее наша работа.` а в будущем с позволения модераторов появляются подобные вопросы [**ссылка**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5069/234502). `Как результат, все, что не касается тематики сайта, было вынесено на Мету и в чаты` Да вот только вопрос про пояс-бэтмена был на основном сайте и был там не один день. Или сообщение не соответствует действительности или политика администрации сильно изменилась к настоящему времени. Больше информации здесь [**ссылка**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5048/234502)

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом ваш вопрос относится к теме данного обсуждения?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky это не мой ответ, это мой комментарий, комментарий на ваш ответ, я пользователь данного сайта и могу оставлять комментарии если они не нарушают правил. Данный вопрос не закрыт для новых ответов и комментариев. В своем ответе вы сделали заявление, я его прокомментировал. Тем более вы модератор, публичное лицо на данном ресурсе, на ваши ответы можно ссылаться.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov На мой взгляд, ваш комментарий не относится к теме __данного вопроса__, и должен быть удален.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky Это **комментарий** на ваш ответ, реакция на ваше заявление `Проблема шума`, вы дали ответ и сделали заявление о проблеме шума в сообществе, именно его я и прокомментировал. Вы публичное лицо на данном ресурсе, на ваши заявления можно ссылаться и комментировать их.

Answer (score 5):

Моё личное мнение.

Поведение данного конкретного участника нельзя однозначно квалифицировать ни как неприемлемое, ни как приемлемое. Это не чисто чёрное-белое, было гораздо больше полутонов.

Он писал *много* и это некоторыми ([в том числе мной](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32391618#32391618)) воспринималось порой не очень положительно -- но я считал, что вполне достаточно ограничиться советом в чате, а не переводить вопрос в плоскость официальных норм и правил.

Он писал не очень грамотно -- но для меня это не первостепенный вопрос. В то же время я согласен, что интереснее зайти в чат, где есть что почитать, чем в пустой чат: и тут у меня у самого достаточно подвижная позиция. Порой мне нравится живой чат: хорошо, когда у тебя выдаётся день посвободнее и звёзды так сложатся что есть ещё несколько людей у которых так же совпали свободные часы. Обычно же, работа держит весьма плотно.

Временами проскальзывали сообщения очень грубые (приводилась [подборка](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32565286#32565286)), но я не видел ни одного случая, когда бы такое предложение собрало бы хотя бы половину страницы обсуждения. Это не умаляет серьёзность нарушений -- скорее говорит о нашей толерантности. Я пожалуй, могу вспомнить, что и ко мне были похожие не очень уместные обращения -- но то, что мне приходится напрягать для этого память говорит о том, что в тот момент я вообще не придал этому значения и тут же забыл. Вообще, эпизодически у каждого бывают неудачные фразы, но тут они явно системные и участник сам не осознаёт, что такое поведение явно неприемлемо. Острого негатива в чате публично не было: либо все так же промолчали, либо обсуждали с модераторами лично. Значит ли это, что такое поведение допустимо? Вовсе нет. И если участник этого не понял сам, не донесло сообщество -- значит, пришла пора переводить вопрос в более официальное русло, через инструменты модерирования.

Для меня очевидно, что наказание должно быть. Несколько неожиданно было, что оказывается за участником уже были ранее множественные нарушения -- у меня сложилось впечатление, что об этом никто не знал и общались как общались, без какого-то ощущения, что с клеймённым преступником общаешься.

Из этих двух факторов (что не запомнилось много скандалов; что такой длинный срок бана) привело к массовому недоумению: а что так жёстко-то наказали?

Количество звёзд в чате на этом сообщении набралось уже 7 штук (сравним с 12тью звёздами).

Я хотел было высказаться на тему, что инкрементальность бана нужно применять только для злостных нарушителей, которые явно имеют деструктивные намерения снова и снова вернуться и "отомстить".
По сути, за данного конкретного участника высказывались мнения, что мол, да он же вменяемый, посмотрите, он всё поймёт и так, зачем такой длинный бан?

Подумав, наверное ограничусь двумя комментариями на тему срока.

Во-первых, увеличение срока бана ограждает сообщество от попыток DoS'а. Чтобы на регулярных нарушителей ("невменяемый") тратить минимальное количество времени.

Во-вторых, увеличение срока бана даёт как раз некоторую гарантию, что <вменяемый> человек (в отличие от явно деструктивного регулярного нарушителя) начиная с некоторого порога наконец-то осознает, что его поступок плохой и приводит к печальным для нарушителя последствиям. Цепочка "поступил плохо к другим -- будет плохо тебе самому" очень проста. Тут каждый сам делает свой выбор: готов ли он скорректировать своё поведение, чтобы существовать в социуме не задевая окружающих или польза от сообщества настолько мала по сравнению с желанием самовыразиться за счёт окружающих, что готов тихо отчалить с ресурса.

В конкретном случае, исходя из истории прошлого опыта (толи четыре, толи семь банов) нет никакой гарантии, что именно сейчас, после очередного наказания придёт понимание, что такое поведение не очень хорошо. Почему именно сейчас, почему раньше не приходило? Тут скорее как раз важно соблюдать именно постепенное увеличение срока бана, чтобы иметь какие-то гарантии, что после некоторого предела наступит понимание, что нет смысла продолжать старую линию поведения.

Так что в целом поддерживая решение о бане мне чисто по-человечески жаль, что понимание не пришло раньше и что так сложилось. Возможно, с обоих сторон были какие-то упущенные шансы выправить ситуацию, но увы, не были реализованы.

Comment: @StackOverFollow, кроме Вас сбором таких материалов вряд ли кто займется.

Comment: Чёрное/белое - это больше философия, а тут реальные действия. Тут уже вопрос установленной тут системы наказаний.

Answer (score 4):

Поддержу бан.
**Причина:** В чате отдыхают, общаются, балагурят порой, но коллективом.
И когда кто-то начинает чушь нести или даже оскорблять пользователей (возможно неумышленно, но тем не менее), это надоедает. Особенно когда этот кто-то очень безграмотен в письме.
Для реальных и/или важных вопросов есть RU.SO.

---

Но хотелось бы узнать откуда такой срок?
Вроде уже за четвёртое нарушение вечный покой виртуальной души.

**P. S.** Да, да, меня модераторы подкупили чтобы я на их сторону стал.
Продал душу Николасу.

Comment: в воспитательных целях я бы банил человека на день - неделю, но не на год. Молодые люди обучаемы, "настоящих" оскорбления от него не было, возможно, бывал фамильярен, но не год же.

Comment: 7-мая блокировка намекает что "обучаемы" - это не тот случай. Фамильярность не пугает особо, но сообщения из найденной тут коллекции говорит что лучше ограничить деструктивность ТС'а.

Answer (score -3):

я против такого долгого бана.

я не против банов в принципе, не против минусов и т.д.

но - я верю в воспитание людей, которые хотят учиться.

и кроме того, правила бана в enSO и ruSO должны различаться хотя бы потому, что на ruSO гораздо меньше людей, наши правила должны быть мягче.

Comment: Не хочу минусовать, просто не поставлю плюс. И -- процитирую старый анекдот: "...внезапно подскользнулась, упала и напоpолась на нож... И так восемь pаз подpяд, господин судья!"

Comment: @StackOverFollow, да, мало надежды, что вопрос о сроке бана на чат вынесут на общее голосование. А о нем (грядущем строгом бане и конкретных притензиях) админы Вас предупреждали?

Comment: @AK  те его высказывания, которые я видел, imho на такой бан не тянут (и всерьез обижаться на них умным людям не стоит)

Comment: @StackOverFollow, т.е. никто по человечески ни разу (поедыдущий бан я тоже имею в виду) на почту не писал и что конкретно Вы нарушали не говорил?

Comment: @avp вполне с вами соглашусь, я отдельный ответ писал о том же: крупных скандалов не было, громогласно обиженных тоже. Если я правильно понимаю, причина такого срока -- это _карма_, предыдущие баны в количестве 4 штук. Если бы это был первый бан -- я уверен, что такого срока не было бы. Но раз они есть -- то никуда не деться, срок _обязан_ быть увеличен. Просто за то, что имеет место повтор, рецидив. И я не знаю, за что были баны -- даже если каждый раз разные поводы это не повод снижать срок: иначе серийные нарушители будут чередовать разные нарушения.

Comment: @StackOverFollow К моему великому сожалению я вижу, что вы не очень достойно ведёте себя и прибегаете к манипулятивным приёмам. Например, воззвание "мой дорогой друг, не подставляйся, это не нужно" -- это попытка изобразить из себя жертву и втянуть в треугольник Тиран - Жертва - Спаситель явно симпатизирующего вам strangeqargo. Другие примеры -- в ныне удалённом вашем ответе, поэтому не буду к нему апеллировать. Вы реально сейчас расстроены, и только отягощаете ситуацию своими высказываниями.

Comment: @StackOverFollow, а попробуйте лично написать модератору и поговорить о снижении срока, скажите, что осознали и не будете часто на отвлеченные темы и т.п. А так,  остается надеяться, что мы не единственные друзья, с которыми Вы можете на эти темы общаться. В любом случае, в основном-то сайте все осталось по прежнему.

Comment: `Меня не станет` (и вы будете виноваты в этом) -- это лишь ещё одна манипуляция. Вы не хотите замечать свои манипуляции? Дело не в том, что вы кого-то другом называете -- дело в том, как вы рубаху на себе прилюдно рвёте. Я вам как-то рекомендовал книгу про психологию (Э. Бёрн "Игры, в которые играют люди"), по-прежнему рекомендую прочитать. Та игра, которую вы ведёте -- называется "пьяница". Многоходовая, богатая событиями игра. Украл -- выпил -- в тюрьму -- repeat. Крест можно целовать прилюдно, обещая, что уж в этот-то раз точно исправитесь и завяжете с алкоголем.

Comment: К вам весьма хорошее отношение было, многое даже спускалось на тормозах. И даже сейчас я вполне вижу, что есть люди настроенные вполне неплохо -- я, strangeqargo, avp. Но с каждым вашим шагом вы всё больше начинаете плодить негатива. Фактически вы ставите себя на положение Жертвы, а мы, которые не хотим выступать в роли "Спасителя" (именно так, в кавычках) в ваших глаза становимся вашими "Тиранами". Треугольник замыкается. Вам бы реально взять паузу, чтобы вы ещё больше не сделали поступков, о которых будете жалеть.

Comment: @StackOverFollow, я не думаю, что модераторы решили Вас специально травить и т.п., как это Вам хочется сейчас представить и как Вы это описываете. Просто, так получилось. Попробуйте успокоиться и через некоторе время (пару недель) "отыграть назад".

Comment: Разве тех преступников, которых предупреждали и даже обвиняли по этой статье, не судят строже, чем обычно? Именно из-за того, что они точно знают что за это грозит, но сознательно шли на нарушение. Если не согласен с правилами, то совет везде один - создавай свой сайт и делай там что хочешь.

Comment: @StackOverFollow Голосование? Посмотрите на оценки, выставленные вопросу, ответам и отдельным комментариям. По-моему это уже вполне высказанное сообществом отношение к вопросу.

Comment: @StackOverFollow ты все-таки утрируешь, и наверняка тебе действительно стоило остыть, а потом попросить о пересмотре сроков. Если когда-нибудь вопросы технические возникнут - в моем профиле меня легко найти, удач.