# Отсутствует перевод при блокировке аккаунта

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Все долго [обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3776/%D0%91%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B-your-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-by-a-moderator-and-cannot) недавнюю блокировку пользователя @StackOverfollow, но почему-то никто не заметил, что уведомление о блокировке не имеет перевода:

> Your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 416 days

Comment: С большой вероятностью, это сообщение показывается в чате. Чат не локализован вообще.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky значит, будет первый камень в огород чата :) Есть ли какие-то предпосылки (озвучивалось ли это на enSO) к тому чтобы его локализовать?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, каких–либо планов по локализации системы чатов нет, к сожалению.