# Информация по поводу блокировки

Tags: обсуждение

1. Хочу узнать, буду ли я заблокирован если я не буду заходить в чат? Допустим, я зарегистрировался под новым ником, и не захожу в русскоязычный чат, чтобы меня не блокировали. А то получается, теперь мне нужно диапазон выкнинуть на свалку.
2. Я буду блокирован всегда и везде так как вы будете применять свои полномочия дабы увидеть мой IP–адрес, вычислить и наказать меня вне зависимости в чате я или нет?
3. Расскажите, как поступить так, чтобы у меня мог быть никнейм на ру со, но он не был бы заблокирован в чате? Не общаться и не заходить в чат в течении года? Уже пол года прошло! Так что срок мой должен был укоротиться, а вы только продлеваете его. Ну да ладно.

Comment: Чтобы не блокировали, надо соблюдать правила и прислушиваться к мнению, которое высказали еще в прошлый раз. Но, судя по всему, вы это всё не усвоили.

Comment: Как это не усвоил ? я ведь не флудил в чате, общался и то редко. Просто хочу что бы меня больше не блокировали, я не хочу скрываться делать мультиаки и так далее, просто я в этот раз сделал - потому что заскучился за вами :) и хотел не много пообщаться. Просто хочу как то решить эту проблему если это возможно. Я не хочу по новой подымать все эти старые темы и все что было. я понимаю что я был слишком к вам привязан и надоедал флудом. Просто для вас это был флуд а для меня это знак внимание и дружбы (правда черезмерный...)

Comment: Обещаю вести себя хорошо и не нарушать правила.

Comment: [Неужели я был прав](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=34172423#34172423).

Comment: @alexolut вы просто хороший :)

Comment: Так что за решения вы приняли ?
Нужно удалить все аккануты тогда, опять, включая этот и старый, я почему то думал что я старый аккаунт удалил. Но оказываеться он жив. Ну пусть тогда стоит как памятник в музеи. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Существование нескольких аккаунтов у одного человека само по себе не является сколько-нибудь предосудительным. Наказывается только создание дополнительных аккаунтов с целью продолжить нарушение правил сообщества.

   [Вот детали о конкретно вашем случае блокировки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3776/%D0%91%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B-your-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-by-a-moderator-and-cannot). И да, вы создали дополнительный аккаунт и пришли заниматься примерно тем же, за что и были заблокированы.
2. См. п. 1. Система работает несколько сложнее. Вас заблокировали не за то, что ваш аккаунт дублирует аккаунт нарушителя, а за точно такое же нарушение правил. Тот факт, что вы рецидивист, влияет только на **срок** блокировки.

   Но это **обычная** процедура. В вашем случае нарушение очень тонкое и труднодоказуемое, оно долго накапливает раздражение в сообществе, пока это раздражение не выливается, наконец, в блокировку. Тот факт, что аккаунт был связан с известным ранее нарушителем, достаточно веское доказательство того, что вы продолжите в том же духе и достойны блокировки. Это скорее помогло зафиксировать факт нарушения. А дальше всё как обычно.

   То есть, если вы всё-таки прочитаете материалы по вашей первой блокировке, приведённые по ссылке выше, и не будете продолжать создавать "шум" и далее, то и санкций к вам применять не будут. Не за что будет.
3. См. п. 2. Срок продлён за рецидив. Поскольку рекомендации до сегодняшнего дня вы не воспринимали, с нашей стороны остаётся только блокировка. С вашей — следование уже выданным вам (сообществом) рекомендациям.

Comment: Разве срок был продлён? было 416 стало бесконечность? я что-то пропустил?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский *"так что срок мой должен был укоротиться а вы только продлеваете его"* таки чушь?

Comment: Эм. Как-то неожиданное объяснение, я вижу ситуацию совершенно в ином ключе. Нарушений новых не было (т.е. формально "я пришёл и сидел тихо - на меня никто не жаловался"), поэтому вы апеллируете к гипотетическому "я точно знаю, что он гарантированно продолжит" (эдакая презумпция виновности). Я полагаю всё проще: сам факт создания аккаунта с целью обойти наказание -- это и есть (повторное) нарушение правил сообщества. Попытка обхода наказания ДОЛЖНА  наказываться.

Comment: @AK его в чате уже сравнивали со StackOverFollow. Модераторы могли запросто счесть это жалобой. Но я не модератор :) А цель, с которой создаётся новый аккаунт, неясна, пока с этого аккаунта не произойдёт что-нибудь. Эвристика "тот же человек -- та же цель" пока применяется только к спамерам, от которых не только вред, но и гарантированно никакой пользы.

Comment: @D-side видимо я пропустил это.... ну славно, трам пам пам)

Answer (score 5):

Для вас заблокирован доступ лишь к чату русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков. Все остальные сайты сети (включая Stack Overflow на русском), на данный момент, вам доступны.

Удалив предыдущую учетную запись и создав новую, вы хотели обмануть систему. Возможно, ваш номер бы прошел, если бы вы учли рекомендации, данные вам ранее. Блокировка будет пролонгирована на новую учетную запись.