# Уменьшение количества вредоносного шума в комментариях на сайте

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Время от времени на сайте публикуются вопросы, которые не соответствуют правилам сайта. Такие вопросы могут породить большое количество вредоносного шума, что значительно снижает коэффициент сигнал/шум, зародить злость в сообществе и нетерпимость между участниками. Вред приносят не столько сами вопросы, сколько реакция на них — комментарии.

Далеко не все вопросы, которые закрываются на сайте, могут или будут открыты повторно: действительно, существуют люди, которые не понимают, зачем нужен Stack Overflow и почему высококвалифицированные знатоки отвечают на вопросы коллег. Такие люди и их вопросы не являются поводом для наличия «ругани» на нашем сайте. Пожалуйста, помните, что закрытие вопроса — есть много большее наказание, чем любой «язвительный» комментарий, потому что закрытие вопроса не дает автору добиться поставленной цели — получить решение задачи. Если автор вопроса новичок и не понимает, что допустил ошибку, то [«неуместный» комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/) лишь усилит ощущение, что проблема не в вопросе, а в комментирующих. Если автор вопроса заведомо нарушает правила, то он сознательно пропустит любые комментарии не по делу и будет ждать того единственного, кто ответит, а вся ругань достанется нам — участникам сообщества. Таким образом, как ни крути, «неуместные» комментарии только добавляют вредоносный шум на сайт и никогда не помогают улучшить ситуацию.

#### Как бороться с шумом?

В первую очередь, голосовать против вопроса, за закрытие и удаление. Вопросы, не соответствующие правилам, являются основной причиной грубости. Если вы проголосовали против и за закрытие, но видите, что другой участник ведет себя несдержанно или недружелюбно, пожалуйста, отметьте такой комментарий тревогой как невежливый или оскорбительный, ведь злость может породить только злость — оскорбления будут расти лавинообразно.

#### Что происходит, когда вы отмечаете комментарий тревогой?

1. Если в комментарии присутствует заранее определенное оскорбительное слово, то [комментарий удалится автоматически системой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/6).
2. В обратном случае отмеченные тревогой комментарии попадают в специальную очередь для проверки модераторами.

Если вы видите какие–либо комментарии, [которые можно считать неуместными для нашего сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/), пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь отмечать их тревогой!

#### Что будет, если какой–то неуместный комментарий останется на сайте?

На ранней стадии сообщества, где–то до 100 вопросов в день, я вручную просматривал большинство вопросов от новичков (вопросы которых являются причиной наибольшего количество вредного шума), пытаясь остановить зашумление информации на сайте. После определенного порога просмотреть все новые вопросы одному человеку стало невозможным, я оставил это дело. На мой взгляд, сегодня вопрос поддержания атмосферы знания и профессионального общения опять встал остро.

Спешу поделиться с участниками программой, которая уже некоторое время помогает мне отслеживать неуместные комментарии. Знакомьтесь, «[модератор комментариев](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so-comment-moderator)». Принцип работы подробно описан на GitHub, продублирую лишь основную идею.

- Программа периодически запрашивает новые комментарии у серверов Stack Exchange через публичный API, затем анализирует их.
- Если комментарии похожи на «оскорбления», они добавляются в RSS–ленту. Лента доступна по адресу `http://benice.rudevs.ru/comments/feed/`. Вы можете добавить ее в любую читалку RSS.
- Я добавил эту ленту в специальный [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73258/). Если в чате появляется новая запись, которая кажется мне «подозрительной», я перехожу в вопрос и пытаюсь понять контекст. Если комментарий действительно неуместен, я использую сигнал тревоги.

Если вы, как и я, не успеваете просмотреть все новые вопросы, но хотели бы принять участие в модерации, пожалуйста, отслеживайте чат или добавьте ленту в любимую читалку!

**Несколько слов про программу**

1. Программа выполняет только классификацию комментариев, она не удаляет их, подтверждает удаление или что–либо еще. Это делает участник непосредственно на сайте через стандартный интерфейс сайта (чудес нет).
2. Программа не распознает абсолютно все неуместные комментарии, и нам крайне нужна ваша помощь «на месте»: если вы столкнулись с неуместным комментарием, пожалуйста, не ждите, что кто–либо найдет его. Отметьте неуместный комментарий тревогой сразу! В дальнейшем мы используем удаленные тревогой комментарии для обучения программы.
3. Программа допускает ошибки и классифицирует обычные комментарии как неуместные. Это нормально. Метрика оптимизации — покрыть как можно больше неуместных комментариев. Если ваш «обычный» комментарий попал в выборку, пожалуйста, не переживайте.

Мы собрались вместе на Stack Overflow, чтобы делиться знаниями с коллегами, помогать другим людям становиться лучше день ото дня и самим открывать для себя что–то новое. Давайте поддерживать культуру сообщества и атмосферу знания на сайте вместе! Доброжелательность, открытость и эмпатия участников к проблемам других — это то, что делает наше сообщество уникальным. Вкупе с получаемыми знаниями наш сайт уже стал незаменимым инструментом для многих разработчиков, а мы, незнакомцы из интернета, самыми близкими, незаменимыми коллегами и наставниками. Развернутые ответы на прикладные технические вопросы и минимальное количество шума — это то, что отличает нас от любого другого сайта. Давайте вместе приложим все силы, чтобы и дальше этот «культурный разрыв» оставался за нами.

Буду рад выслушать ваши отзывы, пожелания и предложения!

Comment: а разве такого вопроса именно про вредоносный шум не было еще?

Comment: @Grundy  Не до конца понимаю ваш вопрос. Пожалуйста, поясните его и, если вам не сложно, приведите ссылку на вопрос, про который вы говорите.

Comment: А, это я похоже с ответами в которых вредоносный шум как раз упоминался, типа [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/186999), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4281/186999) [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3778/186999)

Answer (score 4):

Очень немало комментариев являются просто бесполезными, но неоскорбительными. Было бы неплохо, если бы у нас была реализована функциональность автоматического удаления комменатриев при пометке их тревогой "более не является необходимым". На enSO это уже реализовано, что комментарии вроде "Спасибо" удаляются и не забирают драгоценное время модераторов. Выработка списка шаблонов для автоматического удаления была бы полезной темой после внедрения данной функциональности.

Comment: На самом деле, у нас уже активирован функция [удаления комментариев по одной тревоге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5899/), но для оскорбительных комментариев. Постараюсь исследовать вопрос о «более не является необходимым». Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я где-то читал, что «спасибо» рекомендуется здесь подтверждать голосованием за сообщение.

Comment: @alexolut: полезно, уведомлять новых участников, что "спасибо, работает" можно выразить плюсом на ответе и/или приняв его, но так как существуют ограничения по репутации и времени на голосование и принятие ответа, то *временный* комментарий, который выражает, что не только для ботов ответы пишем, является уместным¶ Можно внести "Спасибо" в список слов, которые позволяют удалить комментарий по одной «более не является необходимым» тревоге (если это не так).

Comment: @jfs Дело в том, что я и сам бывает пишу комментарии "Спасибо", "Не за что" и тому подобное. Но я их сам потом удаляю через небольшое время и смежные помечаю тревогой "более не является необходимым" ввиду бесполезности этого для других. Поэтому пусть хоть каждый говорит "Спасибо" и т.д. Но это должно удаляться через время по нажатию тревоги или собственноручно.